# Developing gnome shell extensions with eclipse as a IDE

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell-extension

I would like to know whether any body has used Eclipse JavaScript support for developing gnome-exensions. Actually aiming here for the context support which is available in eclipse. And i though if i could add all the java scripts that a extension is inheriting (base scrips) in to a user library, then i could included it as a dependency in my extension project. Have any once done this already ? Does all the methods that are used in a exentions exist in the base scripts ? In what directories does the base scripts exist ?
So far i tried adding the scripts in the following directory but still i have error when i try to look at the journal gnome extension code.
/usr/share/gnome-shell/js
/usr/share/gjs-1.0

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you the reading of [GnomeShell Extensions Step By Step Tutorial](https://wiki.gnome.org/Attic/GnomeShell/Extensions/StepByStepTutorial) that explains how to configure Eclipse and gives a tutorial to develop GnomeShell extensions.